# PrintStream cannot be resolved to a type. Why?

Tags: java, printstream

```
PrintStream ps1, ps2;
```

My compiler tells me that

> PrintStream cannot be resolved to a type

Why? This is my professor's code. Why doesn't it work? I thought you could use `PrintStream` as a type so that you can also write `ps1=System.out` for example.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O if you're on eclipse. You need to import the class.

Comment: As @Nicholas K said `Ctrl + Shift + O` is a shortcut for organizing imports on eclipse. Or you can just past `import java.io.PrintStream;`

Comment: Did you even import the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My compiler tells me that "PrintStream cannot be resolved to a type".
>   Why?

you need to import [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) class. Just add `import java.io.PrintStream;` at the beginning of your script.